# React proxy uses the wrong url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, request

I have react app with proxy to my node js server `http://localhost:3000` and `http://localhost:9000`
In my package.json react app:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:9000",
...
```

Some request wrong works.
Example: 
I on `http://localhost:3000/admin` on my react app and i create request to server

```
fetch('admin/check-token',
                {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization':Cookie.getCookie(TOKEN)
                    },
                })
                .then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((json) => {
                    console.log(json)
                })
                .catch(function (res) {
                    console.log(res)
                })
```

I need request to `http://localhost:9000/admin/check-token`, but i have error and chrome show me that i send request to `http://localhost:9000/admin/admin/check-token`.
As I understand it, the extra `/admin` is taken from `http://localhost:3000/admin`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser URL(`window.location.href`) is `http://localhost:3000/admin` and the URL string provided for fetch is `admin/check-token`. They are getting appended, as per the design. To use only the domain part from browser URL, start your URL string of fetch with `/`, like,

```
fetch('/admin/check-token', ...)
```

Or you can provide the fully qualified URL, like,

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/admin/check-token', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would only have to use two /admin if you have your express routes, for example in your main file  you have

```
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes)
```

Then in your  admin routes

```
 adminRoutes.post('/admin', (req, res) => {
  // do stuff
  })
```

Then your fetch would look like

```
fetch('http://localhost/admin/admin', {
  method: "POST" //etc...
  })
```

But if you are using jsonwebtoken you should be using middleware on the backend

```
adminRoutes.post('/adminTasks', authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
  // if authenticateToken do stuff
})
```

I will show the authenticateToken function for a better example

```
function authenticateToken(req, res, next){
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    if(token == null) { return res.sendStatus(401) }

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN, (err, user) => {
        if(err) { return res.sendStatus(403) }
        req.user = user;
        next();
    })
```

}